# Automator exits on launch

Tags: mac, crash, automator

When I open Automator, I get:

`7/1/12 10:54:26 AM   com.apple.launchd[1]    (com.jft.PdaNetMac[57449]) Exited with exit code: 1`

in console. I would like to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`com.jft.PdaNetMac` appears to be the bundle identifier of PdaNetMac.app.

If you just removed its app bundle without running an uninstaller, try downloading the pkg from [its website](http://junefabrics.com/android/mac.php) and running the uninstallation script. It removes a kernel extension in addition to the launchd property list.

```
sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.jft.PdaNetMac.plist 
sudo rm -R /System/Library/Extensions/PdaNetDrv.kext 
sudo rm -R /Applications/PdaNetMac.app 
sudo rm ~/PdaNetUninstall.sh 
echo "PdaNet has been uninstalled, please reboot your computer"
```